# GCP Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) Backups remain after deleting the isntance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, backups

We have recently started using GCP Cloud SQL, and have been testing backup and restores.  We have done the following and seem to have backups that are not associated with an instance, and we can't remove them.

We created a database and have started using it.
We created a backup schedule for the database backup and wanted to test the restoration process.
We created a clone of the database, and then tested a restore from the original backup.  This was all fine and worked as expected.
We left the clone running for a few days, then decided that it was not needed anymore.
We deleted the clone, but by this point, it had created a few backups.
If we run the

```
gcloud sql backups list --instance -
```

It shows all backups, including 3 from the deleted instance, this is strange, as backups are supposed to be removed when the instance is deleted (if they are automated).  If try to run

```
gcloud sql backups delete [ID]
```

I get a http403 error saying not authorized (I am a GCP admin, so have all permissions)

We have tried re-creating the instance with the same name, but the backups are presumably linked via an ID, not name.

Does anyone know:

a) Will we be changed for this?
b) Is there a way to delete these
c) it may well be a legitimate scenario to want to keep backups, and may be restore them later.  the restoration process does not work for these orphaned backups, we have tried
d) I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035060/keep-backup-for-deleted-cloudsql-instance), does anyone know if Google have progressed this?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's best to reach [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) for such scenarios.

Comment: Yes, as also comment above, It would be helpful to reach out to cloud support for detailed investigation and suggestion with these type of scenarios.

Comment: Google basic support only really offer billing support, not technical support, they suggest some community based support, one of which is stack overflow, hence why I posted here.  If you know where I can report this issue, please do send me a direct link that I can use.  Since then, the files seem to have disappeared, which is strange, they have been there for about 9 months.